# Cookie missing in Restsharp response but not in Postman

Tags: c#, postman, restsharp

I am able to use Postman and successfully login with a WebAPI using Postman and get a cookie for the following requests.

I grab the code from Postman and put in Visual Studio C# using RestSharp. However with Visual Studio and RestSharp, the request comes back as successful ok 200 but there's NO COOKIE.

What am I missing? I have been looking on the web for 4 days.

Thanks for your help. Below is the C# code from Postman:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://client.awebsite.ca/user/login?_format=hal_json");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "a16887c6-a1da-fa25-e721-621c4b19318b");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\"name\":\"firstname.lastname\", \"pass\":\"passwordoffirstnamelastname\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: why you know there is no cookie?

Comment: Hi  Badulake,i looked in reponse.cookies and the count was 0.
However, after adding the cookie container to the client as suggested by Ben Hall, I looked deeper in that cookie container object after executing the request and could find a cookie and use it for my later tasks.
Thanks Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like you have created a `CookieContainer`.

See: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Cookies

```
var client = new RestClient("https://client.awebsite.ca/user/login?_format=hal_json");
client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

// Your request code...

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```